# Java Drools - REST Call Timing Out - Out Of Memory

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, drools

I am implementing Drools in a Java Project, version 6 of the below dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I intent to invoke the rules by calling a REST API, built with spring 4.3.0.RELEASE. In my config class, I am loading the drools script from database:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAsync
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.bla.bla.api.app")
@ImportResource({ "classpath:datasources-context.xml" })
public class AppConfig {
 private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(AppConfig.class);  
 public @Autowired IServiceDao serviceDao;
```

The rules are then being stored in a global variable as list in a `@Repository` annotated class:

```
@Repository
public class ServiceDao implements IServiceDao
```

In the above ServiceDao there is a method, invoked at the post construct stage:

```
@PostConstruct
    private void init() throws IOException {
        log.debug("Initializing ruleevaluation API Context");

        // Initializing rules:
        serviceDao.initializeRules();
    }
```

, that reloads the rules from database and initializes the drools environment:

```
public void initializeRules() {
        

        // 1. Load Rules:
        log.debug("Initiating Rules...");
        rules.clear();
        rules = loadRules();

        //  2. Initialize Drools Environment:
        try {

            initializeDrools();

        } catch (DroolsParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
```

the method 'initializeDrools()' is implemented as below:

```
private void initializeDrools() throws DroolsParserException, IOException {

        PackageBuilder packageBuilder = new PackageBuilder();
        RuleBase ruleBase = RuleBaseFactory.newRuleBase();
        
        // This script will contain all the rules combined in one Drools script:
        String completeRulesDroolsScript = "";
        // Initialize script with object imports:
        completeRulesDroolsScript = ""
                + "import com.bla.model.svc.RuleRequest             \r\n"
                + "import com.bla.model.svc.RuleResponse        \r\n\n\n";

        if (rules != null) {

            if (rules.size() > 0) {
                for (RuleObject ruleObject : rules) {

                    // Add each individual Drools rule expression to the complete Drools script:
                    completeRulesDroolsScript += ruleObject.getExpression();
                    completeRulesDroolsScript = completeRulesDroolsScript .concat("\n\n\n");
                }
            }

        }

        try {
            packageBuilder.addPackageFromDrl(new 
            StringReader(completeRulesDroolsScript));
            org.drools.core.rule.Package rulesPackage = packageBuilder.getPackage();            
            ruleBase.addPackage(rulesPackage);
            
            this.setWorkingMemory(ruleBase.newStatefulSession());
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            log.error("!!! Could not Initialize Drools Engine !!!");
        }
        
    }
```

Next is the REST method, in a separate controller class:

```
@RestController
public class RuleEvaluationController
```

which simply calls the backend service from ServiceDao class:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/evaluateRule")
    public ResponseEntity<RuleEvaluationResponse> evaluateRuleData(
            @RequestBody RuleEvaluationRequest ruleEvaluationRequest) {     

        RuleEvaluationResponse ruleEvaluationResponse = new RuleEvaluationResponse();
        try {

            // 1. get the parameters list:
            log.debug(ruleEvaluationRequest.toString());
            
            RuleEvaluationResponse response = serviceDao
                    .evaluateRule(ruleEvaluationRequest);

            log.debug("response = " + response.getEntry());

            return new ResponseEntity<RuleEvaluationResponse>(response,
                    HttpStatus.OK);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            log.error("!!!!! Exception Occurred:" + e.getMessage());

            // set request id, and date in millis:
            ruleevaluationResponse.setRequestId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            ruleevaluationResponse.setDate(System.currentTimeMillis());

            ruleevaluationResponse.setErrorCode(Constants.FAILURE);
            ruleevaluationResponse.setErrorDescription(e.getMessage());

            return new ResponseEntity<RuleEvaluationResponse>(ruleevaluationResponse,
                    HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
```

Where *serviceDao.evaluateRule*  simply inserts the request and response objects, and then fires the rules:

```
public RuleEvaluationResponse evaluateRule(RuleEvaluationRequest request) {

        RuleEvaluationResponse response = new RuleEvaluationResponse();

        this.getWorkingMemory().insert(response);
        this.getWorkingMemory().insert(request);
        this.getWorkingMemory().fireAllRules();

        log.debug("Response = " + response.getEntry());

        return response;
    }
```

At first this all works, and I am getting the rules evaluated successfully and the expected response is obtained. However after 4 or 5 REST calls, the next rest call takes forever and never returns a response and after a while I get an out of memory error.

Can anyone tell me what am I missing here? any hints and advice are highly appreciated. Please feel free to ask for more details if the above info is insufficient.

Thanks

Comment: You're reusing a single stateful session? Or am I misunderstanding this line: `this.setWorkingMemory(ruleBase.newStatefulSession());`. Is there a cleanup somewhere that you're not showing us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide all code so maybe you have cleanup somewhere else
but it looks like you are inserting and calling `.fireAllRules()` and not cleaning up. My code works with KieSession and looks more or less like this:

```
kSession = container.newKieSession("name");
kSession.insert(...);
kSession.insert(...);
kSession.insert(...);

kSession.fireAllRules();
Object[] objects = kSession.getObjects();
kSession.dispose();
```

You may have to change your code. https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.1.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#d0e3555
The statefull session described in the doc requires deleting objects after first `fireAllRules()` call. So you either create stateless session and dispose of it every time or use stateful session and delete old objects before inserting new.

I would probably go with stateless (because I am doing it already ;)

```
[...]
try {
    packageBuilder.addPackageFromDrl(new 
        StringReader(completeRulesDroolsScript));
    org.drools.core.rule.Package rulesPackage = 
        packageBuilder.getPackage();            
    ruleBase.addPackage(rulesPackage);
        
    this.setWorkingMemory(ruleBase.newStatefulSession());
}
[...]
```

I am assuming all the heavy lifting (parsing DRL, etc.) is happening before `newStatefulSession()` call and creating
a session is not 'expensive'.

Comment: He's reusing a single stateful session, it's in the "setup" code in the original post. (`ruleBase.newStatefulSession()`)

Comment: but if I dispose of the session will it be available for subsequent REST calls? kSession is a global object initialized at the startup of the application, so disposing of it will make it unavailable later on. Might give an error like: "Illegal method call. This session was previously disposed."

Comment: thank you @user3075118, I will take that into consideration. But for now I will use the kieSession disposal as u mentioned in your earlier post.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the hints and advice provided, they were helpful in finding the solution.

I solved the problem as follows:

First I migrated to new syntax of version 6.*.*, using KieSession.

first I initialized the Kie Components as below:

```
// Define Kie Service from the Drools factory:
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();

// Define Drools Kie Repository to house the rules:
KieRepository kr = ks.getRepository();

// By default, a Kie File System is defined. In this case rules are NOT being
// read from the *.drl file, but instead fetched from Database.
KieFileSystem kfs = ks.newKieFileSystem();

// Write rules into the Kie file system. Specified file is irrelevant and can be
// empty, since we are not reading from *.drl file.
kfs.write("src/main/resources/com/rule/tempRules.drl", completeAccountingRulesDroolsScript);

// Define rule builder of the rules in file system object:
KieBuilder kb = ks.newKieBuilder(kfs);

// Build all rules in the script.kieModule is automatically deployed to
// KieRepository if successfully built.
kb.buildAll();

// Define new session container. This container is global and will be available
// for all subsequent rule invocations:
kContainer = ks.newKieContainer(kr.getDefaultReleaseId());
```

In my REST call I replaced the code with the following:

```
kSession = kContainer.newKieSession();
kSession.insert(response);
kSession.insert(request);
kSession.fireAllRules();

Collection<? extends Object> objects = kSession.getObjects();
kSession.dispose();
```

and now the variable kContainer is a global variable initialized only on startup. At the end of each REST call I am disposing of the session. Future calls will create a kie session for each call. Could use your input if this is best approach.

@user3075118 @
Roddy of the Frozen Peas

thank you for the hint, it was the one that solved the issue.

Comment: One little thing I would add is `newKieSession(); try { ...using session...} finally { kSession.dispose(); }`

Comment: Also, don't know how your rules work, maybe all you need is in your response object and you don't need to call `getObjects()` and then not use the returned value.

Comment: The outcome of the rule/s is in the inserted `response` object, so I don't have much use of the `kieSession.getObjects()`, perhaps in the future I will modify my approach and get the objects from session. Thanks for the note.

Comment: In the future if you see performance problems, you might want to look into session pooling. I'd also suggest upgrading to Drools 7 at some point too.